# Wordpress content is getting outside of the container

Tags: php, css, wordpress

i am using Wordpress together with Foundation to build my theme.
The content thats been created with Wordpress keeps going outside the parent
container. The title stays inside its container but the

keeps getting out.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="large-7 column">
<?php query_posts('cat=3&posts_per_page=6'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

<?php the_title('<h4 class="entry-title"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' .  
the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h4>'); ?>

<div class="entry-content">
<p style="display:inline;"><?php the_content(__('Continue reading', 'example')); ?></p>

</div>
<p class="byline">
<span class="author vcard"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span> <span class="sep">|                                                                                        
</span> 
<abbr class="published" title="<?php the_time(__('l, F jS, Y, g:i a', 'example')); ?>">  
<?php the_time(__('F j, Y', 'example')); ?></abbr>
<?php edit_post_link(__('Edit', 'example'), ' <span class="sep">|</span> <span    
class="edit">', '</span> '); ?>
</p>
</div> 

<?php endwhile;?>
</div>
<div class="large-5 column">

</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use google chrome inspector to find the offending css. You may also want to use overflow or word-wrap on your content. 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp

Comment: in google chrome its giving the right sizes for the divs

Comment: Word-break works, but now its also seperating letters from words

Comment: `the_content()` will output html markup that could break your markup.
try: `<?php $output = get_the_content(); echo strip_tags($output); ?>`

Comment: grab the page source for the above and css and create a jsfiddle. Much easier to see whats going on. The div's seem fine, so another option is there might be a max-height in one of your classes.